# How I can get $(logname) inside systemd exec command?

Tags: bash, systemd, services

I'm writting a systemd service (`/etc/systemd/system/name.service`). This service execute a script placed in `~/folder/script.sh`. I can't use `~/` inside the `ExecStart` command so I use `/home/$(logname)/folder/script.sh` but it don't work.

Comment: The use of a tilde or /home/$logname indicates that this is a user-based service; is that correct? If it's a system-level service, perhaps the script should not be in a user's home directory?

Comment: @JeffSchaller that's correct it's a user-based service. I want to have the script in that folder because it's the script's folder for an application

Comment: Since it's a user-based service, have you tried using ` $HOME/.config/systemd/user` as the [service's location](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20File%20Load%20Path)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Systemd operates at a lower level than your shell environment. By this I mean, when you execute a command it is normally a child process of your shell environment which is a child process of your init daemon (systemd in this case). That means systemd units don't see or obey your shell environment nor shell macros like `~`. Any environment variables configured in files like `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` don't apply. To see what *does* apply you can type the command `systemctl show-environment`. On my systems (Ubuntu Server and Arch) that's `PATH` and `LANG`. More info [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines).

This all holds true (more or less) for user units too... but systemd maintains a slightly more robust environment for user units as you should see with `systemctl show-environment --user`. If you ran that last command it should have given away what you need to do. Systemd (on my systems at least) sets the environment variable `USER` to the username of the user the unit is being executed as. So change your ExecStart line to `/home/${USER}/folder/script.sh`. That should do it. Also note that I didn't use `(` & `)`... according to the systemd manual pages this shouldn't be necessary. The curly brackets (`{` & `}`) are there in case, for some very strange reason, you have spaces in your usernames. You could also use `${HOME}/folder/script.sh` which would work even if the user's home directory is somewhere other than `/home/`.

Comment: Very usefuls commands to understand the environment where you are running your scripts. I have some syntax errors, is $LOGNAME instead of $logname what my environment support (Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)). Thanks!